# I get a TypeError: express.json() is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I'm a beginner and I've been using github-learning-lab.
It states to use `app.use(bodyParse.json())` to perform a POST request, but VSCode states that 'body-parse' is deprecated.

I searched online and most people say to use `app.use(express.json())` for the current version of Express

My express version: 4.17.1

My node version: 14.17.0

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

const mockUserData = [
    {name: 'Mark'},
    {name: 'Jill'}
]
app.get('/users', function(req, res){
    res.json({
        success: true,
        message: 'successfully got users. Nice!',
        users: mockUserData
    })
})
// colons are used as variables that can be viewed in the params
app.get('/users/:id', function(req,res){
    console.log(req.params.id);
    res.json({
        success: true,
        message: 'got one user',
        user: req.params.id
    })
})

app.post('/login', function(req,res){
    // Typically passwords are encrypted using something like bcrypt before sending to database
    const username = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;

    // This should come from the database
    const mockUsername = 'billyTheKid';
    const mockPassword = 'superSecret';

    if (username === mockUsername && password === mockPassword) {
        // In practice, use JSON web token sign method here to make an encrypted token
        res.json({
            success: true,
            message: 'password and username match!',
            token: 'encrypted token goes here'
        })
    } else {
        res.json({
            success: false,
            message: 'password and username do not match'
        })
    }
})

app.listen(8000, function(){
    console.log('server is running')
})
```

```
Macs-MBP:node-express-course mac$ node server.js
/Users/mac/Documents/node-express-course/server.js:4
app.use(express.json());
                ^

TypeError: express.json is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mac/Documents/node-express-course/server.js:4:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
```

```
Macs-MBP:node-express-course mac$ head node_modules/express/package.json
{
  "_from": "express",
  "_id": "express@4.17.1",
  "_inBundle": false,
  "_integrity": "sha512-mHJ9O79RqluphRrcw2X/GTh3k9tVv8YcoyY4Kkh4WDMUYKRZUq0h1o0w2rrrxBqM7VoeUVqgb27xlEMXTnYt4g==",
  "_location": "/express",
  "_phantomChildren": {},
  "_requested": {
    "type": "tag",
    "registry": true,
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the Express version you think you do? Try `cat node_modules/express/package.json | jq .version` (or just open the file and check the version). The JSON middleware is only available from v4.16.0

Comment: I checked the `package.json` its v4.17.1

Comment: That's very strange then. I cannot reproduce this problem at all. Are you sure everything is spelled correctly? Make sure you copy / paste your exact code into the question above. Please also copy / paste the exact error message in full

Comment: I just updated it.

Comment: Last resort, try the old `rm -r package-lock.json node_modules && npm install`

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled express. I may have made a mistake when installing it initially. I should've tried this from the start. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

A very similar thing happened to me I was trying to run the middleware:

```js
app.use(express.json())
```

But there was the same type of `error` then I reinstalled `express` and this problem got resolved

Answer (score -1):

First you could use Bodyparser or you should reinstall it, but I recommend using Bodyparser

Comment: I did initially but it says bodyparser is deprecated. Apparently it's only available for versions older than 4.16.1. I'll try reinstalling

Comment: BodyParser **is** deprecated as it has been incorporated into Express itself